# How do I edit source code on netbook and build (and debug) project on desktop computer in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, remote-debugging

I have a powerful desktop computer and a netbook sharing the same network over wifi. I'd like to be able to make the desktop computer build project I made changes in on my netbook (because desktop computer is more powerful and will do it faster than netbook).

I have considered usng some remote observation and control tools (like Teamviewer or Radmin) but their most important disadvantage is slow text editing (keystrokes from netbook transferring to desktop pc and back as an image takes some time).

Answer (score 0):

How about installing an SSH demon like the one in Cygwin, http://www.cygwin.com and then using MSBuild or devenv.com to build your project on the command line?

The disadvantage is of course that errors are printed to the SSH console and you would need to manually go to the source lines in the IDE on the netbook.